# Set the view for a 2D matlab plot

Tags: matlab, plot

Assuming I have a "standard" 2d plot, no 3D stuff. My x axis has a range of [0 1000], my y axis has a range of [-5 2400]. I want to set the view automatically after plotting to

x: [200 800]
y: [400 1000]

(as an example). How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`xlim()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) and [`ylim()`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/ylim.html) functions.

Comment: those functions work but the new range is just written over the old one. Example: http://abload.de/img/overridemar7v.png

Comment: @Anonymous: Something is very wrong there; that definitely shouldn't happen.

Comment: Wow... could you post your code? It looks like something else is going wrong.

Comment: @Anonymous It looks like you've draw a plot on top of another one, try calling `clf`, redraw the plot and then try Oli's solution again.

Comment: It seems that a clf solved this problem. actually i cannot repeat this error, it works now